# Mule hot deployment not working on mac

Tags: deployment, mule

In the mule-deploy-properties file, I have set redeployment.enabled=true however this is not working, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check in the mule studio menu that Project->Build Automatically is checked.

Comment: Yes, it's checked. I also open Anypoint Studio through the terminal as a root user without success.

Comment: did you changed anything in studio recently? because i am using it on mac and it is working fine for me.

Comment: One more thing are you able to see your mule flow files(xml) entry in mule-deploy.properties file, e.g config.resources=groovy.xml,practiceproject.xml

Comment: No, I didn't change anything in Studio. And yes, I can see my mule-deploy.properties file, and I have:
    redeployment.enabled=true

Comment: As you said, I have to set Project->Build Automatically, my mistake was that I didn't reopen Anypoint Studio. 
Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Glad that your problem resolved